# Why doesn't global $wp_query not get hooked?

Tags: php, hooks, init, infinite-scroll

I have a plugin that helps me to make lazy loading on posts of a custom post type. The idea is to add an action to the template_redirect/init and get data from the global $wp_query to make jquery understand how much loading there needs to be done.
The plugin php file looks like this:

```
function pbd_alp_init() {
   global $wp_query;

   // Add code to index pages.
   if( !is_singular() ) {   // can i select a specific post type here?
      wp_enqueue_script(
        'pbd-alp-load-posts',
        plugins_url( 'js/load-posts.js', __FILE__ ),
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0',
        true
      );

      // What page are we on? And what is the pages limit?
      $max = $wp_query->max_num_pages; // this returns 0
      $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') > 1 ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

      // Add some parameters for the JS.
      wp_localize_script(
        'pbd-alp-load-posts',
        'pbd_alp',
        array(
            'startPage' => $paged,
            'maxPages' => $max,
            'nextLink' => next_posts($max, false)
        )
      );
  }
}
add_action('init', 'pbd_alp_init');
```

Im sure that max_num_pages function returns a number when i call it directly - why does my global $wp_query seem to be empty?
In the documentation it says that the action should hook to the 'template_redirect' but 'init' seem to be more right? Both doesn't hook up to the wp_query..

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), you can see the order things happen.

Note where `init` is, the query object doesn't exist until the `wp` action.

```
// ...
init
└─ widgets_init
register_sidebar
wp_register_sidebar_widget
wp_default_scripts
wp_default_styles
admin_bar_init  
add_admin_bar_menus 
wp_loaded
parse_request
send_headers
parse_query
pre_get_posts
posts_selection 
wp
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks Milo - but the template_redirect doesn't work either?

Comment: scripts should be enqueued on `wp_enqueue_scripts` action. `var_dump( $wp_query )` and see what it contains.

Comment: isn't that whats happening?

Comment: `wp_enqueue_scripts` is the action within which you should use the `wp_enqueue_script` function.

Comment: ahh - but how do I achieve that? :-)

Comment: the php variables data seems to get transferred to my js file fine though?

Comment: in `add_action`, change the action to `wp_enqueue_scripts`, that's the correct hook to add scripts on. I don't understand your other comments, the data is available to your script, what isn't working then?